# W3Schools Framework, stacking 3 cards side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a school project creating a test website.

I am currently using the W3Schools CSS framework and I am using cards from the framework and no matter what I try I can not get them to stack side by side.

I currently have 3 cards I am trying to stack next to each other.

I attempted to use the float tool but it would just float the top card to the left and the rest would stay below it.

Any insight on this would be awesome, thank you!

Here is my code.

```css
#classes {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}

.w3-card-2 {
 width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 15px 40px;
 padding: 15px 15px;
 float: center;
}


.classes img {

 width: 100%;
}










/* W3.CSS 4.12 November 2018 by Jan Egil and Borge Refsnes */
html{box-sizing:border-box}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:inherit}
/* Extract from normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal git.io/normalize */
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}
audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block}progress{vertical-align:baseline}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}
a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}
a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}
dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sub{bottom:-0.25em}sup{top:-0.5em}figure{margin:1em 40px}img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}
button,input,select,textarea{font:inherit;margin:0}optgroup{font-weight:bold}
button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}
button,html [type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button}
button::-moz-focus-inner, [type=button]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}
button:-moz-focusring, [type=button]:-moz-focusring, [type=reset]:-moz-focusring, [type=submit]:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}
legend{color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}textarea{overflow:auto}
[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{padding:0}
[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}
[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:inherit;opacity:0.54}
::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}
/* End extract */
html,body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5}html{overflow-x:hidden}
h1{font-size:36px}h2{font-size:30px}h3{font-size:24px}h4{font-size:20px}h5{font-size:18px}h6{font-size:16px}.w3-serif{font-family:serif}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;margin:10px 0}.w3-wide{letter-spacing:4px}
hr{border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee;margin:20px 0}
.w3-image{max-width:100%;height:auto}img{vertical-align:middle}a{color:inherit}
.w3-table,.w3-table-all{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-bordered tr,.w3-table-all tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-hoverable tbody tr:hover,.w3-ul.w3-hoverable li:hover{background-color:#ccc}.w3-centered tr th,.w3-centered tr td{text-align:center}
.w3-table td,.w3-table th,.w3-table-all td,.w3-table-all th{padding:8px 8px;display:table-cell;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.w3-table th:first-child,.w3-table td:first-child,.w3-table-all th:first-child,.w3-table-all td:first-child{padding-left:16px}
.w3-btn,.w3-button{border:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;color:inherit;background-color:inherit;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-btn:hover{box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-btn,.w3-button{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}   
.w3-disabled,.w3-btn:disabled,.w3-button:disabled{cursor:not-allowed;opacity:0.3}.w3-disabled *,:disabled *{pointer-events:none}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn:disabled:hover{box-shadow:none}
.w3-badge,.w3-tag{background-color:#000;color:#fff;display:inline-block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;text-align:center}.w3-badge{border-radius:50%}
.w3-ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0}.w3-ul li{padding:8px 16px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
.w3-tooltip,.w3-display-container{position:relative}.w3-tooltip .w3-text{display:none}.w3-tooltip:hover .w3-text{display:inline-block}
.w3-ripple:active{opacity:0.5}.w3-ripple{transition:opacity 0s}
.w3-input{padding:8px;display:block;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;width:100%}
.w3-select{padding:9px 0;width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-dropdown-click,.w3-dropdown-hover{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
.w3-dropdown-hover:hover .w3-dropdown-content{display:block}
.w3-dropdown-hover:first-child,.w3-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-dropdown-hover:hover > .w3-button:first-child,.w3-dropdown-click:hover > .w3-button:first-child{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-dropdown-content{cursor:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff;display:none;position:absolute;min-width:160px;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:1}
.w3-check,.w3-radio{width:24px;height:24px;position:relative;top:6px}
.w3-sidebar{height:100%;width:200px;background-color:#fff;position:fixed!important;z-index:1;overflow:auto}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click{width:100%}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-dropdown-content{min-width:100%}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-button,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-button{width:100%;text-align:left;padding:8px 16px}
.w3-main,#main{transition:margin-left .4s}
.w3-modal{z-index:3;display:none;padding-top:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)}
.w3-modal-content{margin:auto;background-color:#fff;position:relative;padding:0;outline:0;width:600px}
.w3-bar{width:100%;overflow:hidden}.w3-center .w3-bar{display:inline-block;width:auto}
.w3-bar .w3-bar-item{padding:8px 16px;float:left;width:auto;border:none;display:block;outline:0}
.w3-bar .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-bar .w3-dropdown-click{position:static;float:left}
.w3-bar .w3-button{white-space:normal}
.w3-bar-block .w3-bar-item{width:100%;display:block;padding:8px 16px;text-align:left;border:none;white-space:normal;float:none;outline:0}
.w3-bar-block.w3-center .w3-bar-item{text-align:center}.w3-block{display:block;width:100%}
.w3-responsive{display:block;overflow-x:auto}
.w3-container:after,.w3-container:before,.w3-panel:after,.w3-panel:before,.w3-row:after,.w3-row:before,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-cell-row:before,.w3-cell-row:after,.w3-clear:after,.w3-clear:before,.w3-bar:before,.w3-bar:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}
.w3-col,.w3-half,.w3-third,.w3-twothird,.w3-threequarter,.w3-quarter{float:left;width:100%}
.w3-col.s1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.s2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.s3{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.s4{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.s5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.s6{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.s7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.s8{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.s9{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.s10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.s11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.s12{width:99.99999%}
@media (min-width:601px){.w3-col.m1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.m2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.m3,.w3-quarter{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.m4,.w3-third{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.m5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.m6,.w3-half{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.m7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.m8,.w3-twothird{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.m9,.w3-threequarter{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.m10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.m11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.m12{width:99.99999%}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-col.l1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.l2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.l3{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.l4{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.l5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.l6{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.l7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.l8{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.l9{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.l10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.l11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.l12{width:99.99999%}}
.w3-rest{overflow:hidden}.w3-stretch{margin-left:-16px;margin-right:-16px}
.w3-content,.w3-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.w3-content{max-width:980px}.w3-auto{max-width:1140px}
.w3-cell-row{display:table;width:100%}.w3-cell{display:table-cell}
.w3-cell-top{vertical-align:top}.w3-cell-middle{vertical-align:middle}.w3-cell-bottom{vertical-align:bottom}
.w3-hide{display:none!important}.w3-show-block,.w3-show{display:block!important}.w3-show-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}
@media (max-width:1205px){.w3-auto{max-width:95%}}
@media (max-width:600px){.w3-modal-content{margin:0 10px;width:auto!important}.w3-modal{padding-top:30px}
.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content{position:relative} 
.w3-hide-small{display:none!important}.w3-mobile{display:block;width:100%!important}.w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile{text-align:center}
.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-btn,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-button,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button{width:100%}}
@media (max-width:768px){.w3-modal-content{width:500px}.w3-modal{padding-top:50px}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-modal-content{width:900px}.w3-hide-large{display:none!important}.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:block!important}}
@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:601px){.w3-hide-medium{display:none!important}}
@media (max-width:992px){.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:none}.w3-main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}.w3-auto{max-width:100%}}
.w3-top,.w3-bottom{position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1}.w3-top{top:0}.w3-bottom{bottom:0}
.w3-overlay{position:fixed;display:none;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index:2}
.w3-display-topleft{position:absolute;left:0;top:0}.w3-display-topright{position:absolute;right:0;top:0}
.w3-display-bottomleft{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0}.w3-display-bottomright{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0}
.w3-display-middle{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
.w3-display-left{position:absolute;top:50%;left:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-right{position:absolute;top:50%;right:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-topmiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;top:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-bottommiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-hover{display:block}.w3-display-container:hover span.w3-display-hover{display:inline-block}.w3-display-hover{display:none}
.w3-display-position{position:absolute}
.w3-circle{border-radius:50%}
.w3-round-small{border-radius:2px}.w3-round,.w3-round-medium{border-radius:4px}.w3-round-large{border-radius:8px}.w3-round-xlarge{border-radius:16px}.w3-round-xxlarge{border-radius:32px}
.w3-row-padding,.w3-row-padding>.w3-half,.w3-row-padding>.w3-third,.w3-row-padding>.w3-twothird,.w3-row-padding>.w3-threequarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-quarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-col{padding:0 8px}
.w3-container,.w3-panel{padding:0.01em 16px}.w3-panel{margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:16px}
.w3-code,.w3-codespan{font-family:Consolas,"courier new";font-size:16px}
.w3-code{width:auto;background-color:#fff;padding:8px 12px;border-left:4px solid #4CAF50;word-wrap:break-word}
.w3-codespan{color:crimson;background-color:#f1f1f1;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;font-size:110%}
.w3-card,.w3-card-2{box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)}
.w3-card-4,.w3-hover-shadow:hover{box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-spin{animation:w3-spin 2s infinite linear}@keyframes w3-spin{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{transform:rotate(359deg)}}
.w3-animate-fading{animation:fading 10s infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
.w3-animate-opacity{animation:opac 0.8s}@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-top{position:relative;animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-left{position:relative;animation:animateleft 0.4s}@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-right{position:relative;animation:animateright 0.4s}@keyframes animateright{from{right:-300px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-bottom{position:relative;animation:animatebottom 0.4s}@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-zoom {animation:animatezoom 0.6s}@keyframes animatezoom{from{transform:scale(0)} to{transform:scale(1)}}
.w3-animate-input{transition:width 0.4s ease-in-out}.w3-animate-input:focus{width:100%!important}
.w3-opacity,.w3-hover-opacity:hover{opacity:0.60}.w3-opacity-off,.w3-hover-opacity-off:hover{opacity:1}
.w3-opacity-max{opacity:0.25}.w3-opacity-min{opacity:0.75}
.w3-greyscale-max,.w3-grayscale-max,.w3-hover-greyscale:hover,.w3-hover-grayscale:hover{filter:grayscale(100%)}
.w3-greyscale,.w3-grayscale{filter:grayscale(75%)}.w3-greyscale-min,.w3-grayscale-min{filter:grayscale(50%)}
.w3-sepia{filter:sepia(75%)}.w3-sepia-max,.w3-hover-sepia:hover{filter:sepia(100%)}.w3-sepia-min{filter:sepia(50%)}
.w3-tiny{font-size:10px!important}.w3-small{font-size:12px!important}.w3-medium{font-size:15px!important}.w3-large{font-size:18px!important}
.w3-xlarge{font-size:24px!important}.w3-xxlarge{font-size:36px!important}.w3-xxxlarge{font-size:48px!important}.w3-jumbo{font-size:64px!important}
.w3-left-align{text-align:left!important}.w3-right-align{text-align:right!important}.w3-justify{text-align:justify!important}.w3-center{text-align:center!important}
.w3-border-0{border:0!important}.w3-border{border:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-top{border-top:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-bottom{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-left{border-left:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-right{border-right:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-topbar{border-top:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-bottombar{border-bottom:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-leftbar{border-left:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-rightbar{border-right:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-section,.w3-code{margin-top:16px!important;margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-margin{margin:16px!important}.w3-margin-top{margin-top:16px!important}.w3-margin-bottom{margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-margin-left{margin-left:16px!important}.w3-margin-right{margin-right:16px!important}
.w3-padding-small{padding:4px 8px!important}.w3-padding{padding:8px 16px!important}.w3-padding-large{padding:12px 24px!important}
.w3-padding-16{padding-top:16px!important;padding-bottom:16px!important}.w3-padding-24{padding-top:24px!important;padding-bottom:24px!important}
.w3-padding-32{padding-top:32px!important;padding-bottom:32px!important}.w3-padding-48{padding-top:48px!important;padding-bottom:48px!important}
.w3-padding-64{padding-top:64px!important;padding-bottom:64px!important}
.w3-left{float:left!important}.w3-right{float:right!important}
.w3-button:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ccc!important}
.w3-transparent,.w3-hover-none:hover{background-color:transparent!important}
.w3-hover-none:hover{box-shadow:none!important}
/* Colors */
.w3-amber,.w3-hover-amber:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-aqua,.w3-hover-aqua:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-blue,.w3-hover-blue:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-light-blue,.w3-hover-light-blue:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-brown,.w3-hover-brown:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#795548!important}
.w3-cyan,.w3-hover-cyan:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-blue-grey,.w3-hover-blue-grey:hover,.w3-blue-gray,.w3-hover-blue-gray:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-green,.w3-hover-green:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-light-green,.w3-hover-light-green:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-indigo,.w3-hover-indigo:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-khaki,.w3-hover-khaki:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#f0e68c!important}
.w3-lime,.w3-hover-lime:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-orange,.w3-hover-orange:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-deep-orange,.w3-hover-deep-orange:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-pink,.w3-hover-pink:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-purple,.w3-hover-purple:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-deep-purple,.w3-hover-deep-purple:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-red,.w3-hover-red:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#f44336!important}
.w3-sand,.w3-hover-sand:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-teal,.w3-hover-teal:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#009688!important}
.w3-yellow,.w3-hover-yellow:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffeb3b!important}
.w3-white,.w3-hover-white:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#fff!important}
.w3-black,.w3-hover-black:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#000!important}
.w3-grey,.w3-hover-grey:hover,.w3-gray,.w3-hover-gray:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#9e9e9e!important}
.w3-light-grey,.w3-hover-light-grey:hover,.w3-light-gray,.w3-hover-light-gray:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-dark-grey,.w3-hover-dark-grey:hover,.w3-dark-gray,.w3-hover-dark-gray:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#616161!important}
.w3-pale-red,.w3-hover-pale-red:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffdddd!important}
.w3-pale-green,.w3-hover-pale-green:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ddffdd!important}
.w3-pale-yellow,.w3-hover-pale-yellow:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffffcc!important}
.w3-pale-blue,.w3-hover-pale-blue:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ddffff!important}
.w3-text-amber,.w3-hover-text-amber:hover{color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-text-aqua,.w3-hover-text-aqua:hover{color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-text-blue,.w3-hover-text-blue:hover{color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-text-light-blue,.w3-hover-text-light-blue:hover{color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-text-brown,.w3-hover-text-brown:hover{color:#795548!important}
.w3-text-cyan,.w3-hover-text-cyan:hover{color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-text-blue-grey,.w3-hover-text-blue-grey:hover,.w3-text-blue-gray,.w3-hover-text-blue-gray:hover{color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-text-green,.w3-hover-text-green:hover{color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-text-light-green,.w3-hover-text-light-green:hover{color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-text-indigo,.w3-hover-text-indigo:hover{color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-text-khaki,.w3-hover-text-khaki:hover{color:#b4aa50!important}
.w3-text-lime,.w3-hover-text-lime:hover{color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-text-orange,.w3-hover-text-orange:hover{color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-text-deep-orange,.w3-hover-text-deep-orange:hover{color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-text-pink,.w3-hover-text-pink:hover{color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-text-purple,.w3-hover-text-purple:hover{color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-text-deep-purple,.w3-hover-text-deep-purple:hover{color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-text-red,.w3-hover-text-red:hover{color:#f44336!important}
.w3-text-sand,.w3-hover-text-sand:hover{color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-text-teal,.w3-hover-text-teal:hover{color:#009688!important}
.w3-text-yellow,.w3-hover-text-yellow:hover{color:#d2be0e!important}
.w3-text-white,.w3-hover-text-white:hover{color:#fff!important}
.w3-text-black,.w3-hover-text-black:hover{color:#000!important}
.w3-text-grey,.w3-hover-text-grey:hover,.w3-text-gray,.w3-hover-text-gray:hover{color:#757575!important}
.w3-text-light-grey,.w3-hover-text-light-grey:hover,.w3-text-light-gray,.w3-hover-text-light-gray:hover{color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-text-dark-grey,.w3-hover-text-dark-grey:hover,.w3-text-dark-gray,.w3-hover-text-dark-gray:hover{color:#3a3a3a!important}
.w3-border-amber,.w3-hover-border-amber:hover{border-color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-border-aqua,.w3-hover-border-aqua:hover{border-color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-border-blue,.w3-hover-border-blue:hover{border-color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-border-light-blue,.w3-hover-border-light-blue:hover{border-color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-border-brown,.w3-hover-border-brown:hover{border-color:#795548!important}
.w3-border-cyan,.w3-hover-border-cyan:hover{border-color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-border-blue-grey,.w3-hover-border-blue-grey:hover,.w3-border-blue-gray,.w3-hover-border-blue-gray:hover{border-color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-border-green,.w3-hover-border-green:hover{border-color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-border-light-green,.w3-hover-border-light-green:hover{border-color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-border-indigo,.w3-hover-border-indigo:hover{border-color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-border-khaki,.w3-hover-border-khaki:hover{border-color:#f0e68c!important}
.w3-border-lime,.w3-hover-border-lime:hover{border-color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-border-orange,.w3-hover-border-orange:hover{border-color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-border-deep-orange,.w3-hover-border-deep-orange:hover{border-color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-border-pink,.w3-hover-border-pink:hover{border-color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-border-purple,.w3-hover-border-purple:hover{border-color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-border-deep-purple,.w3-hover-border-deep-purple:hover{border-color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-border-red,.w3-hover-border-red:hover{border-color:#f44336!important}
.w3-border-sand,.w3-hover-border-sand:hover{border-color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-border-teal,.w3-hover-border-teal:hover{border-color:#009688!important}
.w3-border-yellow,.w3-hover-border-yellow:hover{border-color:#ffeb3b!important}
.w3-border-white,.w3-hover-border-white:hover{border-color:#fff!important}
.w3-border-black,.w3-hover-border-black:hover{border-color:#000!important}
.w3-border-grey,.w3-hover-border-grey:hover,.w3-border-gray,.w3-hover-border-gray:hover{border-color:#9e9e9e!important}
.w3-border-light-grey,.w3-hover-border-light-grey:hover,.w3-border-light-gray,.w3-hover-border-light-gray:hover{border-color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-border-dark-grey,.w3-hover-border-dark-grey:hover,.w3-border-dark-gray,.w3-hover-border-dark-gray:hover{border-color:#616161!important}
.w3-border-pale-red,.w3-hover-border-pale-red:hover{border-color:#ffe7e7!important}.w3-border-pale-green,.w3-hover-border-pale-green:hover{border-color:#e7ffe7!important}
.w3-border-pale-yellow,.w3-hover-border-pale-yellow:hover{border-color:#ffffcc!important}.w3-border-pale-blue,.w3-hover-border-pale-blue:hover{border-color:#e7ffff!important}
```

```html
<section class="classes">
    
      <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-half"></div>
          <div id="mobilerepair" class="w3-card-2">
            <div id="essentials">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cG5KxDD.jpg" alt="squirrel">
              <h2>Mobile Repair</h2>
              <p>From cracked screens to bad batteries, we repair phones, tablets,                          laptops, and many other android & apple based mobile devices.</p>
            </div> <!-- ====END ESSENTIALS -->
          </div> <!-- =====END CARD 2===== -->
        </div> <!-- =====END HALF===== -->
        <div id="databases">
          <div class="w3-half"></div>
            <div id="desktoprepair" class="w3-card-2">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cG5KxDD.jpg" alt="barn">
              <h2>Desktop Computer Repair</h2>
              <p>In Web Databases you will learn ow to setup and                                            structure a Database of the tomb stones using MySql</p>
            
            </div> <!-- =======END DATABASES======= -->
          </div> <!-- =======END HALF==========-->
        </div> <!-- =======END CARD 2==========-->
        <div id="server">
          <div class="w3-half"></div>
            <div class="w3-card-2">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cG5KxDD.jpg" alt="home">
              <h2>Networking</h2>
              <p>From your home or small buisness, we can setup and manage all your networking needs, from security, to data management and full IT support services.  </p>
            </div><!-- ============END SERVER======= -->
          </div> <!-- =======END HALF==========-->
        </div> <!-- =======END CARD 2==========-->
        
        </section>
```

Comment: CSS cascades, so if your code is intended to override some of the minified styles, it will not. Moving them to the bottom may help. Further, I am going to suggest either un-minifying the 3rd party code or removing it altogether because it is rather difficult to reason with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a technique known as a "clearfix". This is the selector:

```
.w3-container:after, .w3-container:before, .w3-panel:after, .w3-panel:before, .w3-row:after, .w3-row:before, .w3-row-padding:after, .w3-row-padding:before, .w3-cell-row:before, .w3-cell-row:after, .w3-clear:after, .w3-clear:before, .w3-bar:before, .w3-bar:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Removing this will allow you to resolve the problem with:

```
.classes > * {
    float: left;
}
```

Another way around the problem is to use flex. Without any of the above steps, this works:

```
.classes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

---

I will offer my opinion that working with a large quantity of (especially minified 3rd party) code like this will not be particularly easy. I suspect learning it will be simpler if you can reduce the code you are working with to a minimum that can be managed a little better.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked great, In our class we were taught to use this framework but I will work on using it as little as possible as I move forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is your css
#classes {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
.w3-card-2 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 15px 40px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    float: center;
}
.classes img {

    width: 100%;
}

In your css a parent class have width of 960px and this parent div it self have three child and as per your css class you assign with 400px to each div.
According to me this is not correct you must have the use child div width according to the parent div width for i.e.

#classes {
    float:left
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
.w3-card-2 {
    float:left
    width: 310px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 15px 5px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}
.classes img {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
Always use float left in case your child div is not align to each other, in above css you can reduce the width and audjust the marginform form left and right
```